# Deserialization of JSON response in C#

Tags: c#, json, spotify, json-deserialization

I want to deserialize a response (from Spotify Web Api) in JSON to C# Objects.

As I'm super new to JSON, I have no idea how to do it even after reading a lot of MSDN articles!

This is the response in JSON: https://api.spotify.com/v1/search?q=artist:slayer&type=album

I tried http://json2csharp.com to analyze the response and create Classes based on them.

This is what the website gave me:

```
public class ExternalUrls
{
    public string spotify { get; set; }
}

public class Image
{
    public int height { get; set; }
    public string url { get; set; }
    public int width { get; set; }
}

public class Item
{
    public string album_type { get; set; }
    public List<string> available_markets { get; set; }
    public ExternalUrls external_urls { get; set; }
    public string href { get; set; }
    public string id { get; set; }
    public List<Image> images { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string type { get; set; }
    public string uri { get; set; }
}

public class Albums
{
    public string href { get; set; }
    public List<Item> items { get; set; }
    public int limit { get; set; }
    public string next { get; set; }
    public int offset { get; set; }
    public object previous { get; set; }
    public int total { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public Albums albums { get; set; }
}
```

I have no idea what to do with it! Should I use Json.Net or DataContractJsonDeserializer? And how?!

Can someone tell me what would be the rest of my code:

```
using (var client = new WebClient())
{
    Byte[] get = client.DownloadData(@"https://api.spotify.com/v1/search?q=artist:slayer&type=album");
    using (var stream = new MemoryStream(get))
    {
        // What to do now?
    }
}
```

**UPDATE:** I used the following code based on other similar questions, so far my listBox1 will remain empty after the execution of this code:

```
using (var client = new WebClient())
{
    Byte[] get = client.DownloadData(@"https://api.spotify.com/v1/search?q=artist:slayer&type=album");
    using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(get))
    {
        var json = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(string[][]));
        var response = (string[][])json.ReadObject(stream);
        for (int i = 0; i < response.Length; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < response[i].Length; j++)
                listBox1.Items.Add(response[i][j].ToString());
    }
}
```

Isn't JSON suppose to be array of string arrays?

Comment: The `string[][]` part from the duplicate is where you put your `RootObject` class.

Comment: @CodeCaster Can you show me an example?